# Format the print statement in Python

Tags: python, output

I have a script that takes in a txt file with a list of attributes that go as input to the program. For each attribute, it prints out the attribute name if it satisfies the conditions of the script. However, each attribute may be satisfied multiple times and the output prints it many times. I'd like to do this now:

```
condition 1 satisfied by A,B,C,D
condition 2 satisfied by A,B
condition 3 satisfied by B,D
```

How do I do this?
My current output looks like

```
A
A
condition 3 not satisfied by A
B
B
B
condition 1 not satisfied by C
condition 2 not satisfied by C
C
D
condition 2 not satisfied by D
D
```

Comment: what form are the satisfying attributes in before they are printed?

Comment: Please show a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code and data and explain what precisely the difference between expected and actual outputs is and what you've tried to do about it so far.

Answer (score 0):

how about this (in pseudo python code)

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for attr in [A, B, C, D]:
  for cond in [condition1, condition2, ...]:
     if attr satisfies cond:
        result[cond].append(attr)

print result
```

Output:

```
{cond1: [A, B], cond2: [A], cond3: [C,D], ...}
```

I'm not sure that is what you want. You haven't stated clearly (enough) what your input looks like and what you want as output.